# Conditional probability involving black-box functions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability, random-variable

Let X be a continuous random variable subject to a given probability density function. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two black-box functions, i.e., we don't know the form of the functions but can only query them for specific values $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $Y_f = f(X)$ and $Y_g = g(X)$ be the random variables induced by applying $X$ to $f$ and $g$ respectively.

Which algorithms/data structures exist to compute and represent the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(Y_g \mid Y_f)$ assuming that $Y_f$ and $Y_g$ are not independent?

Comment: It's difficult to see what this setup provides that is any different from stating you have a bivariate random variable $(Y,Z)$ with completely unknown distribution and asking how to perform a regression analysis of $Z$ against $Y.$  This is a general statement of the nonparametric regression problem.  Could you point out how your assumptions might imply any useful restriction on the scope of the question?

Comment: The only property that might have some influence on the choice of a good algorithm is that $f$ takes significantly more time to evaluate than $g$. Other than that I am simply interested in different ways on how to compute/represent the conditional probability in this setting.

Comment: The relative cost of $f$ and $g$ doesn't matter, but their total cost determines how many pairs of data you might collect.  That still leaves us with an extremely general, unfocused question.  Could you provide more specifics of the situation you face?

Comment: What would be an example of a restriction/assumption that renders my question less unfocused in your opinion?

Comment: A description of the problem you are abstracting from.

Comment: I am curious about which methods can be applied in principle in this setting involving black box functions. The only minor addition is that I am also interested in the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(Y_g \geq 0 \mid Y_f \geq 0)$. My question is basically about algorithms/methods that can be applied in this setting.

Comment: The problem is that there is a huge number! There's an enormous literature on nonparametric regression methods.  Indeed, almost all of machine learning can be considered a small subset of this literature: $Y_f$ is an explanatory variable and $Y_g$ is what you wish to predict.

Comment: I would appreciate to see some selection of methods. It does not have to be exhaustive. Relevant keywords are enough so that I can dig deeper. Thanks for your input already.